# How to wait until Android Studio virtual machine is fully loaded

Tags: python, android-studio, android-emulator, adb

After running my virtual machine with this command in Python:

```
os.system('emulator -avd Galaxy_Note9_API_27 -writable-system -no-snapshot-update-time')
```

I try to wait with another command (command below) until the device is fully loaded

`os.system("adb -s emulator-5554 wait-for-device shell 'while [[ -z $(getprop dev.bootcomplete) ]] ; do sleep 1; done'")`

But my problem with the above code is that it is a **while loop** but I want it to be in such a way that if after 120 seconds of waiting for the device to load it will return an error to me because I encounter this problem a lot that my device would crash when running and I would get stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: If you use Python why use shell code? How to implement a loop in Python is documented on hundred questions here on SO. Also `time.sleep(1)` isn't difficult to find. Then just count the loops or compare the elapsed time and you got it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you are using `python` to invoke `adb` command, however if there's a reason, you can use `subprocess`, for many other reasons but because it supports timeout too, instead of `os.system`:

```
subprocess.run(["adb", "-s", "emulator-5554", "wait-for-device"], timeout=120)
```